# zomato api support is stopped I am not able to access it?

Tags: zomato-api

I am tryping  to use the zomato api for my project, but I am not able to access the https://developers.zomato.com/ zomato there is {"message": "This API is no longer supported"} response for developer link.
In document or on wen site they have not mentioned that they have closed the support for developer api.
Is there is any way i can access zomato api.